# Can't able to receive the output file

Tags: java

If i try with small amout of data i can receive the output file, if i use large amount of data i can't able to receive the output file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\subha\\eclipse-workspace\\airports_full.txt"));
    String res = "";
    for (String line : lines) {
        int idx = 0;
        while (idx < line.length()) {
            if (line.charAt(idx) != '"') {
                res += line.charAt(idx);
                idx += 1;
            } else {
                int end = line.substring(idx + 1).indexOf('"') + 2;
                res += line.substring(idx).substring(0, end).replaceAll(",", " ");
                idx += end;
            }
        }
        res += "\n";
    }
    Files.write(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\subha\\eclipse-workspace\\newsample1.txt"), res.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
}
```

}

Comment: Hint: do not parse CSV data manually. There are plenty of libraries that do that for you. Rest assured: parsing CSV is more complicated than you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("data.txt"));
    String res = "";
    for (String line : lines) {
        int idx = 0;
        while (idx < line.length()) {
            if (line.charAt(idx) != '"') {
                res += line.charAt(idx);
                idx += 1;
            } else {
                int end = line.substring(idx + 1).indexOf('"') + 2;
                res += line.substring(idx).substring(0, end).replaceAll(",", " ");
                idx += end;
            }
        }
        res += "\n";
    }
    Files.write(Paths.get("output.txt"), res.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
}
```

Comment: I used this code but i can't see any output. Its blank

Comment: Are you printing the output or writing to the file?

Comment: i am writing this string in a file and then trying to replace comma  and then write the replaced string into another file

Comment: @Subha did you tried this I have updated just now just change the path with your file path and check

Comment: Yes i tried but i got an error in this line only List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("data.txt"));

Comment: it shows the error on List. I got this below error The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>

Comment: which version of java are you using?

Comment: i am using verion 8

Comment: may be you have imported `import java.awt.List;` check once it should be `import java.util.List;`

Comment: Now its working, Thank you so much :) @deadshot

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format is always the same, you can make something like this:

```
    String test = "101,\"152/3 Anna nagar Chennai\",2000";
    int idx1 = test.indexOf("\"");
    int idx2 = test.indexOf("\"", idx1);
    String subst = test.substring(idx1, idx2);
    subst = subst.replace(",", "");
    String result = test.substring(0, idx1) + subst + test.substring(idx2);
```

This works if you don't have " in another part of the String and if you have just one comma between the double quotes. If you have more than one, you can use replaceAll.